# How can I set Date object to null in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, object, null

I am trying to set `check_date` to `null`
I tried

```
new Date as 0, null
```

but none of them are working for me. How can I achieve this?

Code

```
  async lastDayToLive() {
        const allDiner  = await this.amazon.findAll({ where: { flight: 'L' } });
        const len = allDiner .length;
        const lastDinker = allDiner [len - 1];
        const { a,} = lastDinker;
        await this.amazon.update(
            { flight: 'land', check_date: `${new Date(0)}` }, --------------------> Here
            { where: {a}}
        );

        
    }
```

Comment: How is this not working: `check_date: null`?

Comment: But do you mean by "not working"? Do you mean whatever you pass that object to is not doing what it's supposed to? Because `check_date: null` will set `check_date` to `null`, no question about it.

Comment: The issue is clearly not here: `{ flight: 'land', check_date: null }`. It's somewhere up the pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set a Date to `null`. Date is an an [embedded JavaScript type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Setting date to `new Date(0)` just sets it to [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)).

You can, however, *set a variable to `null`*.

This should work:

```js
var check_date = null;
```

or, in your case:

```js
        await this.amazon.update(
            { flight: 'land', check_date: null }, 
            { where: {a}}
        );
```

Comment: There are no "embedded JavaScript types". Values have a [*Type*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-ecmascript-language-types) (number, string, etc.) and there is a [built–in](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-built-in-object) [*Date* object](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date-objects).